# No `api-manager.xml` configuration file inside WSO2 Identity server

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to configure **WSO2 Identity Server** as a key manager for **WSO2 Api Manager** by following [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager) tutorial.

In that, under step-4, following instructions are there.

> For this purpose open the /repository/conf/api-manager.xml
>   file and change the  element that appears under the
>    section, so that it points to the API Manager server.

But there is no `api-manager.xml` file inside `<IS_KM_HOME>/repository/conf/`. I'm using **WSO2 Identity Server 5.6.0**.

Does anyone know where can I find this `api-manager.xml` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XML file exists only in WSO2 IS as a Key Manager (WSO2 IS-KM). Please refer[1][2]. You can download the IS as KM from [2]. For API Manager 2.6.0, IS as KM version is 5.7.0. IS 5.6.0 is not a Key manager hence it will not include that configuration file.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager
[2]https://wso2.com/api-management/install/key-manager/

Thanks